# Disable JButton when not logged in

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, disabled-control

I am creating a mini project.  My project is a library management system.

[image: This is my login page]

How can I disable the issue button in advanced search if I am logged in by clicking `Anonymus`?
Or how can I enable the issue button if logged in as administrator?

[image: this is my advance search for books]

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). 2) See [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9554657/418556) 3) Anonymus -> Anonymous

Comment: I'd create yourself some kind of session singleton manager hat could provide you with information about who is currently logged and maybe even the permissions the current user has (or has methods to check the permission), I'd then use this to determine what the current user can and can't do

Answer (score 2):

You can enable / disable buttons using the `setEnabled()` method. You will have to figure out the code for the `boolean` that needs to be passed to the method.

Answer (score 2):

Basically, what you need to do is to call `setEnabled(isAdministrator())` on your Issues button. For this, you'll have to implement an `isAdministrator()` method, which should check if a user is logged in and if that user is the/an administrator. How to check this depends on the implementation of your login dialog and on how you administer your users. Normally you'd have some kind of database holding all users and (encrypted) passwords as well as a flag telling if a certain user is an administrator (or you can have a separate table with roles or permissions and a many-to-many relation between the user table and the roles or permissions table but for a mini-project this is probably not needed).

Answer (score 0):

Just make a boolean variable initialized as false when you validate through username and password change it to true, buttons have a jButton.setVisibility("true or false"); this can either be true or false but adding the boolean variable there will determine whether its a registered user or an anonymous client :)